# 何も言うでない ! meaning and origin

Tags: etymology, dialects, imperatives, role-language

I have found this sentence in Odin Sphere. I guess it's kind of old fashion for a strong interdiction.
I first thought it came from the negative form of  である  but it doesn't seem to be replaceable by ではない.

Does anyone know the origin of this form?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, ～するでない is an old-fashioned and pompous way of saying "Don't do ～!".

In modern Japanese, this is a kind of 役割語 (stereotyped role words) which is typically used by nobles and/or old people in manga and samurai dramas. This seems to have been used a lot more 100 years ago or so, because I can find many similar expressions (eg. 泣くでない, 穢すでない, 淋しがるでない) in 青空文庫.

As for the etymology, unfortunately I could not find a good article which explains this. One answer in [this chiebukuro question](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14142846289) says:

> 原型となったのは江戸時代の上方語です。

So it seems to have originated from somewhere in the Kansai region in the Edo period.

In this question (note 1) two people say it's 江戸時代の武士の言葉, but I don't know whether real samurai in the Edo period actually spoke in this way.

Note 1: expired link removed, 02/02/2022