# でねえ in anime - Negative Imperative?

Tags: colloquial-language, imperatives

So **でねえ** is used in the following sentences in *Great Pretender [S01E01]* as a **negative command** and has been translated as such:

> **来るでねえ !**

> Dont come [closer] !

And here as:

> **ふざけるでねえ！**

> Stop messing around

1. **What is it a contraction of ?**
2. **What is the formality level in comparison to Verb+な and verb-ないでください ?**
3. **What nuances does it carry ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This ～でねえ is a contraction of ～でない, which is an old-fashioned negative imperative expression. ない changed to ねえ (/ai/-to-/ee/ contraction).

- [何も言うでない ! meaning and origin](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33807/5010)
- [What is じゃねぇか? What is its original form?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18454/5010)

Both ～でない and ～でねえ are used as part of stereotypical old-fashioned speech, but their typical users are quite different. ～でない is used by pompous aristocrats and royalty, whereas ～でねえ is dialectal and mostly used by rural farmers.

Basically, it's slightly less forcible than 来るな, but it's much stronger than 来ないで.

Comment: By  来ないで do you mean  来ないでください ? Or is ないで an alternative negative imperative ?

Comment: @JapaneseLearner I mean 来ないで as a casual negative request, i.e., "(Please) don't come". 来ないでください is a polite request which is too different from the others.